# How to concatenate a list and ImportValue in CloudFormation?

Tags: aws-cloudformation

Ok, so here's the deal. I'm struggling in a CloudFormation template.

My template, I have something like:

```
Parameters:
  SecurityGroupIds:
  Type: List<AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup::Id>
Resources:
  Service:
    Type: AWS::ECS::Service
    Properties:
      NetworkConfiguration:
        AwsvpcConfiguration:
          SecurityGroups: !Join [ ",", [ !Ref "SecurityGroupIds", !ImportValue !Sub "${param1}-${param2}-efs-SecurityGroupId" ] ]
```

Then for my Parameters file:

```
{
  {
    "ParameterKey": "SecurityGroupIds",
    "ParameterValue": "sg-065f0903f9c1eeaa2,sg-09f820ab09fa69c5f"
  }
}
```

And the value outputted by the CloudFormation Stack `${param1}-${param2}-efs-SecurityGroupId` is a string value of something like `sg-1234567890`.

And I can't seem to get the right format. I essentially want to just add a value to the `SecurityGroupIds` list that comes from another Stack's output.

I feel like I need to somehow "explode" the SecurityGroupIds list, add to it, then pass it to the SecurityGroups configuration?

Comment: What `${param1}` and `${param2}` are supposed to be?

Answer (score 1):

if you are looking for "explode" functionality then take a look at [Split](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/intrinsic-function-reference-split.html)

For your case it should look like this:

```
!Join [",", [!Split [",", !Ref SecurityGroupIds], !ImportValue !Sub "${param1}-${param2}-efs-SecurityGroupId"]]
```